# save files with specific name from site to disk drive

Tags: php

Here is my code, it's not working perfectly. Can anybody help me to identify the problem?

```
$urls = file('list.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($urls as $url) {
    copy(trim($url),"c:/data/$url");
    echo "$url is done";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Some URL's do not exist.

I want each file from URL to be saved with the name of the URL.

A URL will look like: `http://site.com/index.htm`

Comment: Show some contents of this `list.txt` file please.

Comment: @navnav url look like : http://site.com/index.htm

Comment: Do you want to actually fetch the contents of each url? and then save that, or just save a blank `.htm` file with the `$url`'s name?

Comment: @navnav i want that each file will be saved as the name as its url for exemple index of the site.com will be named site.com and saved and the index.htm for the site2.com will be named as site2.com

Comment: @navnav yes fetch the content and named as the url

Comment: so you don't want to include the file name, just the domain? if so, what file format do you want the saved file to be?

Comment: @navnav what i want that fetch the contect of each url and save it with the name or its url but there is some urls must be skipped because they dont exist

Answer (score 0):

```
$urls = file('list.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($urls as $url) {

    $con=file_get_contents($url);
    if($con !== false)
    {    
        if(file_put_contents(trim($url),$con))
        {    
            echo "$url is done";

            //don't really see the point of these, but okay...
            ob_flush();

            flush();    
        }
    }
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: i think is wrong that says "failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections"

Comment: @MetoMe What line of code does that error come from? the `file_get_contents()` or the `if(file_put_contents(trim($url),$con))`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [PHP cURL](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) function:

```
/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_urlData($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

Have it on your PHP file before your existent `foreach`.

**Your code adapted:**

```
$urls = file('list.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($urls as $url) {
  $data = get_urlData($url);
  copy($data, "c:/data/$url");
  echo "$url is done";
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
```

Not tested but should work just fine.